# Hash Table With Coalesced Hashing Instead of Quadratic Probing

Tags: java, hashtable, hashset, coalesce

I am working on taking a HashSet class that is currently using quadratic probing and trying to make it use coalesced hashing instead. I am very new to hashing so the concept of coalesced hashing is very confusing to me. At the moment I am working with the add and remove methods.

Add:

```
public boolean add( AnyType x )
 {
    int currentPos = findPos( x );
    if( isActive( array, currentPos ) )
        return false;

    if( array[ currentPos ] == null ) 
        occupied++;
    array[ currentPos ] = new HashEntry( x, true );
    currentSize++;
    modCount++;

    if( occupied > array.length / 2 )        
        rehash( );

    return true;                   
}
```

and remove:

```
public boolean remove( Object x )
{
      int currentPos = findPos( x );
      if( !isActive( array, currentPos ) )
         return false;

      array[ currentPos ].isActive = false;
      currentSize--;
      modCount++;    

      if( currentSize < array.length / 8 )
          rehash( );

      return true;
}
```

I understand how coalesced hashing works on paper when inserting into a table. But other than that I am really lost on how to implement it in Java.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that looks like you're trying to use coalesced hashing. Can you elaborate on what you've already tried to do so far? What specifically is your question?

Comment: the code above is currently using quadratic probing. I am trying to understand how to implement the same code using coalesced hashing. But because I have little to no knowledge of coalesced hashing I am looking for some guidance on how to recode these two methods. I haven't been able to find any sources for information that I understand well enough to move forward on my own which is why I'm seeking help here.

Comment: The code you've given above doesn't even seem to use quadratic probing - it looks like it fails to insert values if there's a hash collision. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes its a homework assignment. I'm not looking for you to type out the answer for me though I am just trying to better understand Coalesced Hashing so I can do the hw on my own.

Comment: This is the link to the source code I have to use: http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsj4/code/weiss/util/HashSet.java

Comment: Given that you don't yet have a working implementation of quadratic hashing, I think you should pause and work on that first. As your question currently stands, I don't understand what specifically you're asking for. You might want to reword it to more precisely articulate what you've tried, what trouble you're having, and what's not working.